# React Native button with no style

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button

I have a horizontal view:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <Text style={styles.bottomTextSignIn}>I'm already a member, </Text>
   <Button 
      title="Sign In"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
   />
</View>
```

Im trying to make the the `button` look like the `text`, no `styling`, so it looks like its part of the sentence "`I'm already a member, Sign In`"

At the moment its a blue button next to the text. I tried changing the button colour to white which leaves a shadow around it. Is there a way to remove the styling for the button? or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button component is a "touchable/pressable" component with style. [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js)

I think you are looking for [pressable component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable).

```
<Pressable onPress={() => alert('hey')}>
  <Text>I'm pressable!</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: `onPress={() => alert('hey')}>`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the button tag with  and handle on onPress event on the text and different style to the text from the first one